# Console/Command Prompt Full screen in Windows Vista/7

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, console, fullscreen

Is there a way to get the console windows full screen in Windows Vista/7?

I'm looking for a distributable C/C++ solution, library, or emulator.

Microsoft's "[solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/05/01/vista-virtual-pc-and-full-screen-text-display.aspx)" is to install a VM which is pretty ludicrous.

The relevant [super user's question](https://superuser.com/questions/7219/fullscreen-vistas-command-prompt-or-replacement) doesn't have good answers.

For those interested, the full screen console mode isn't available due to WDDM drivers which don't support int10 intercepts.

Comment: What was wrong with Diago's answer to the question on Super User? Specifically, the link [here](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/03/how-to-maximize-vista-command-prompt-window/).

Comment: Most Vista Premium users have the AERO theme enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) source code, modify it to strip toolbars and other visual garbage you don't need and run it in full screen mode.

What it does is starts a command-line shell, redirects the output to its own internal buffers, and then draws the text from those buffers using GDI to a bitmap. Same thing the Virtual PC solution would do, excluding the whole "emulating another OS" layer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it is [not possible any more](https://superuser.com/questions/314675/what-are-the-requirements-for-fullscreen-consoles-in-windows-7), even if you copy and install the *Full screen video driver for console* from XP.

Like you said, the new driver model won’t allow/support it. (So you can also kiss DOS games running without an emulator/VM goodbye.)

Answer (score 0):

Yahh .. Its bit noisy ..but its possible. Simple trick is to go to exact file ,i.e, cmd.exe in C:/ and 
copy the cmd.exe and paste it in desktop. The refer this steps,

cmd.exe >Properties > Compatibility > (Then change the mode to Windows 7) > And Save it.

Again,

Open cmd console > Properties > Layout > Width:300 , Height:300 (change to this).

And enjoy full screen mode(full window) !!